# 94MB file is too large to be uploaded on FAT32 file system

Tags: windows-7, debian, filesystems, samba, fat32

Everything is in the title : I've got a smb share with write access  on a FAT32 file system (I'm aware of the 4GB limit).

I've got 426 GB free of 736 GB  shown on the network drive.

Still if I try to upload a medium sized file (94MB) I get the error :

```
The file 'fileName.extension' is too large for the destination file system.
<Cancel>
```

Do you know what can cause this error ? (maybe a by user quota ?)

And do you know how can I avoid it ?

The smb server is running on a Debian based ARM linux (Cubian on cubieboard)
I access it on my Windows 7 64 pc.

I've install the samba using packages: samba samba-doc samba-common smbfs smbclient
and adding in **/etc/samba/smb.conf** :

```
[SHARE_NAME]
path = /folder
comment = comment
writable = yes
browseable = yes
public = yes
```

Here is the output for `cd /media/path/ ; df .`  :

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      771772352 324799744 446972608  43% /media/MULTIMEDIA
```

It appears that the file name being too long was the cause of this. (Same file with shorter name works fine) So I update my question :  What is this filename length limitation about ? Does it take the full path into account or just the filename itself. and what it the actual limit ?

Comment: "4726 GB free of 736 GB"?

Comment: from the server, whats the output of `cd \path\to\upload\dir ; df .`

Comment: I've edit the mistake 426 Go of 736 ;)

Comment: Now added the output for 'df .'

Comment: I dont know what a samba is, But the error looked to me at first that the files name itself is to long, for the file system, not the data size?

Comment: You're right...  0kb file, very long name : same error. 94Mb file short name : copy without error.  Would you explain us What happens here ?

Comment: You learn something new everyday! Should have remembered this, however!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this table in the Wikipedia:

- [Comparison of file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems)

In the [Limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits) section, you will find that the [maximum filename length is 8.3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) for FAT32 file systems.

> 8.3 filenames have at most eight characters, optionally followed by a period "." and a filename extension of at most three characters. For
>   files with no extension, the ".", if present, has no significance
>   (that is, "myfile" and "myfile." are equivalent). File and directory
>   names are uppercase, although systems that use the 8.3 standard are
>   usually case-insensitive.

Just in case you are wondering, apparently there's no length limit for the path, though.

Comment: I would add, it appear that special characters are longer than normal ones :  a space or a 'é' are considered longer than '_' or 'e'. So we should avoid those characters in filenames.